# JPA filtering entities from a mapped association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My friendships sql table has column `friend_1, friend_2, status`.
I have the following mappings in my (snippet below) `User` class. Currently `user.getInitiatedFriendships` returns list of `Friendships` where value of column `friend_1` is equal to ID of the user I'm calling this getter on.
`user.getInvitedToFriendships()` returns `Friendships` where column `friend_2` is equal to ID of this user.

I want to know if it is possible to add something to this line `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "invitingUser" +>some check if status=0<)` to also perform a check on column `status` and only return those `Friendships` where `status = 0` ?

Thanks

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

        ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invitingUser")
    List<Friendship> initiatedFriendships;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invitedUser"})
    List<Friendship> invitedToFriendships;

        ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I came up for another way to search for it in google and found it. This is the answer:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invitingUser")
    @Where(clause = "status = 0")
    List<Friendship> initiatedFriendships;
```